# Episever MapRequestHandler Returns wrong Physical Path

Tags: file, save, episerver, virtualpathprovider, editmode

Im uploading a file with help of UnifiedDirectory in Episerver 7.1.
The file is saved perfectly when browsed within episerver VPP file explorer.
For instance the path could become something like:

```
Path: XformFiles/xformdata/2015_04_24/file.jpg
```

If i rightclick the file and select edit i can view and edit the file so this works.

But when i open the file in vpp folder open file "editmode" i get 404.

```
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://somesite.no:80/XformFiles/134017_1184046626_m.jpg
Physical Path    C:\something\Main\Site.Web\XformFiles\XformFiles\xformdata134017_1184046626_m.jpg
Logon Method       Forms
```

And it tries to get:

```
C:\something\Main\Site.Web\XformFiles\XformFiles\xformdata134017_1184046626_m.jpg
```

It should be something more like this (we use an network basePath for the VPP folder):

```
\\172.40.1.163\vpp\Epi7_new\XformFiles\xformdata134017_1184046626_m.jpg
```

NOTE: If EPiServer tried to get the file this way above it would most likley work.

EPiServerFramework.config:

```
<add showInFileManager="true" virtualName="XformFiles"
  virtualPath="~/XformFiles/" bypassAccessCheck="true"
      physicalPath="\\172.40.1.163\vpp\Epi7_new\XformFiles"
   name="XformFiles"  type="EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathNativeProvider,EPiServer" />
```

For documents folder we use this (the appDataPath is `\\172.40.1.163\vpp\Epi7_new\` )

```
<add showInFileManager="true" virtualName="Documents" virtualPath="~/Documents/"
      bypassAccessCheck="false" maxVersions="5" useRouting="true"
      customFileSummary="~/FileSummary.config" physicalPath="[appDataPath]\SiteDocuments"
      name="SiteDocuments" type="EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathVersioningProvider, EPiServer" />



  <appData basePath="\\172.40.1.163\Epi7_new" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to add useRouting="true" in Virtual Path Configuration here:

```
  <add showInFileManager="true" virtualName="XformFiles"
  virtualPath="~/XformFiles/" bypassAccessCheck="true"
      physicalPath="\\172.40.1.163\vpp\Epi7_new\XformFiles"
   name="XformFiles"  type="EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathNativeProvider,EPiServer" useRouting="true" />
```